# Изменить игндикатор скрола в таблице

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

Я знаю, что в индикаторе, который показывается при скроле таблицы, есть три стандартных стайла. Мне нужно его изменить. Например, сделать, чтобы его всегда было видно. Сделать такую серую полоску, как будто бэкграунд скрола и на нем белый индикатор, который бегает вверх и вниз. Как это можно сделать? На данный момент есть метод, который меняет просто цвет.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
    verticalIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```